# Disable the "Edit Experience Editor Options" button for my editor users

Tags: content-editor, experience-editor, editor-user-permissions

I have a number of users which should have access to create/edit/delete content on my site, including inserting new components to pages. To ensure that they can insert and change components I have given them the roles:

- sitecore\Designer
- sitecore\Author

With the above roles, the users also get access to the "Edit Experience Editor Options" which is not something I wan't ordinary editors to have access to. Is it possible to limit the access to this?

[image: Edit experience editor options]

Comment: have you tried denying read permission on the appropriate item in the core database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Core DB and navigate to

```
'/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons/Options'
```

& apply corresponding security on this item.

It would look like :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response Balaji. It solved my problem. I was hoping to control it via the built-in roles but they are not as fine grained as I thought.

Comment: That helped mate. Thanks!